# Microsoft Graph API - Unknown Error when querying Shifts

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

When we query the shifts endpoint (in beta ver 0.7.0) with the following code:

`var shifts = await graphClient.Teams[$"{this.teamId}"].Schedule.Shifts.Request().GetAsync();`

We get the following exception

[image: Exception: Code Unknown Error]

This was working ~40 days ago with the beta but now we get this error. We can query teams fine so we know the team ID is working but whenever we try to access shifts we get the above error.

Comment: Strange. Can you share a copy of the request url+body and the response body?

Comment: Hi Michael,
The request URL is https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/OURTEAMID/schedule/shifts
The request body is empty though we are specifying a valid access token on the header using `requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                        new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authenticationResult.AccessToken)`

The response body we get back is

`{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "84f075a5-5479-48e0-8a19-eb2f963bb28c",
      "date": "2019-08-14T08:13:02"
    }
  }
}`

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 1):

Your client code is correct.

I was able to reproduce your error with [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) by trying to make the call with a user who hadn't consented to the Group.Read.All or Group.ReadWrite.All scopes.

Take a look at your access token using [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/). Please add the missing scope to your application registration.

Comment: I added Group.ReadWrite.All to our Azure app but I'm getting the same error. I put my token on jwt.ms and get this as my roles `"roles": [
    "Group.Read.All",
    "Group.ReadWrite.All",
    "User.Read.All"
  ],`

This was with both delegated and application permissions

Comment: @falkon13 who is the actor? Is it a service or user that initiates the calls?

Comment: It's an Azure app registration that initiates the call

Comment: Let preface, I'm not familiar with the Shifts API. I can make a successful calls with Graph Explorer to the API once I set up some shifts. Have you tried to Graph Explorer to test calls? Has the user used the Shifts app to create shifts? I wonder if the user has to use the Shifts app before the shifts API can be used.

Comment: I have tried Graph Explorer however I don't think there is a way to use it as an Azure AD app, only as myself, I have manually created shifts as myself yet I haven't been able to access Shifts App as the Azure AD app. Thank you for your responses, they are appreciated.